# Nested annotations in RelaxNG?

Tags: annotations, relaxng

Trying to get the following XSD output from RelaxNG, using Trang for conversion:

```
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Basic documentation text here.</xs:documentation>
<xs:appinfo>
<jxb:class name="VmlLocation">
<jxb:javadoc>
Javadoc text here.
</jxb:javadoc>
</jxb:class>
</xs:appinfo>
</xs:annotation>
```

.. but none of the methods for declaring annotations seem to work except the RNC '##', which generates one set of annotation/documentation tags.
Methods using brackets seem to be ignored by Trang.
Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trang is somewhat limited, but I know that a:documentation elements that are children of attribute and element elements will be transferred, provided that they contain only plain text (no child elements or attributes).  It's possible that a:documentation works in other places too.  It definitely does not work as the child of a grammar element or define element.